# Swagger + Jersey Numeric Enum in Java

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger

I have a field in my Rest API (Implemented in `Jersey` + `Jackson` + `Bean Validation`) which is a closed set of numeric values. For example, an Employee rank, which can be one of the following values: `1,2,5,7`. And no, defining a matching String for each of the values is not an option.

I'm trying to get the generated `Swagger` docs to present a numeric enum for those value. I've tried the following:

1. Defining an Integer with the property: `@ApiModelProperty(allowableValues = "1,2,5,7") Integer employeeRank` . `Swagger-UI` did not show any enum, only after changing the type of `employeeRank` to `String`.  So unfortunately, `allowableValues` only works with with a String parameter, which I don't want my model to be. employeeRank must be an Integer.
2. Defining an Enum:

   ```
   @JsonSerialize(using = BlockSize.OrderTypeSerializer.class)
   @JsonDeserialize(using = BlockSize.OrderTypeDeserializer.class)
   public enum EmployeeRank {
       ONW(1),
       TWO(2),
       FIVE(5),
       SEVEN(7)
   int rank;

   EmployeeRank(int rank) {
       this.rank = rank;
   }

   @JsonValue
   public int getRank() {
       return rank;
   }

   public class RankSerializer extends JsonSerializer<EmployeeRank> {


       @Override
       public void serialize(EmployeeRank rank, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
           generator.writeStartObject();
           generator.writeFieldName("rank");
           generator.writeNumber(rank.getRank());
           generator.writeEndObject();
       }
   }

   public class RankDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<EmployeeRank> {

       @Override
       public EmployeeRank deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
           int val =jsonParser.getValueAsInt();
           if (val == 1) {
               return ONE;
           }

           if (val == 2) {
               return TWO;
           }

           if (val == 5) {
               return FIVE;
           }

           if (val == 7) {
               return SEVEN;
           }

           throw new IOException("Illiegal rank value " + val);
       }
   }
   ```

With no luck. `Swagger-UI` presents the enum as the enum names (ONE,TWO,FIVE,SEVEN)

3. Overriding `toString` on `EmployeeRank` to return the rank number as string, with or without `JsonValue` annotation on the method. Didn't have any effect.

This seems like a pretty trivial task to define a numeric set of values in Jersey with Swagger to understand it. Any idea?

Below is my ResourceConfig:

```
        resourceConfig.packages(true, ResponseWrapper.class.getPackage().getName());
        resourceConfig.property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
        resourceConfig.property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);


            resourceConfig.register(ApiListingResource.class);
            resourceConfig.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

        resourceConfig.register(EncodingFilter.class);
        resourceConfig.register(GZipEncoder.class);
        resourceConfig.register(DeflateEncoder.class);
        resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(ValidationConfigurationContextResolver.class);
```

And My Swagger initializer:

```
 BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("3.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"https"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage(ApiLevel.class.getPackage().getName());
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
```

**UPDATE**

With the suggestion of @fehguy, I upgraded to `Jackson 2.7`. And there is some progress. Please consider the following enum:

```
public enum Status {
        @JsonProperty("hello")
        ENUM1,
        @JsonProperty("world")
        ENUM2;
    }
```

Running the following main application works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Status user = Status.ENUM1;

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
    }
```

Output is "hello", which is exactly what I needed.

However, `Swagger-UI` still shows the enum values. Maybe it doesn't process `JsonProperty` annotation on enum values?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `toString()` method in the `enum`? To return the integer value (as a string) instead of the constant.

Comment: Have you tried `@ApiModelProperty(allowableValues = "[1,2,5,7]", dataType = "java.lang.Integer")`?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin - it works on the documentation level. However, I believe swagger should be based on the jackson annotations on enum, and not define an entire new enum values just for the documentation. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Hey @Mattan, Do you remember how you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Jackson configuration problem.  Take a look at using the `@JsonProperty` annotation in 2.6.2 or later, which will let you set the friendly name for the enum.

Comment: Well, after upgrading to Jackson 2.7: using @JsonProperty works in a standalone main test program, but somehow Swagger IO still shows the enum values instead of the annotation values. Updated My Question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to customize enum values and generate swagger specification file with them (swagger-ui uses this file) you can do the following.

1. Customize swagger `ObjectMapper` before you create an instance of `BeanConfig`:

```java
import io.swagger.util.Json;

//...
Json.mapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
//...
```

2. Override `toString` method in your enum and add methods annotated with `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonValue`:

```java
public enum Status {
    ENUM1("hello"),
    ENUM2("world");

    private final String value;

    Status(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Rank fromString(final String value) {
        return EnumSet.allOf(Status.class).stream()
                .filter(s -> s.value == value)
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

[image: Model with enum values in Swagger UI]

[image: Request with enum values in Swagger UI]

A simple code example can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/ayakovlevgh/swagger-enum-example).

Comment: The UI still shows the enum names instead of the toString value.

Comment: @Mattan Here is a trivial example to demonstrate that the solution provided in the answer works: https://github.com/ayakovlevgh/swagger-enum-example